# Rolling window polynomial fit in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to compute coefficients from a *n*-degree polynomial applied to a *t*-day window of a time series.  However, I receive an exception `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

My versions are:

- Python 3.6
- pandas version 0.22.0
- numpy version 1.13.3

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
my_ts = pd.Series(data = np.random.normal(size = 365 * 2), index = pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-01', periods = 365 * 2))
coefs = pd.rolling_apply(my_ts, 21, lambda x: np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 3))
```

Yet, when I wrap `np.polyfit` so that it returns only one coefficient, `rolling_apply` has no issue.

```
def pf_wrapper(x):
    coef_lst = np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 3)
    return coef_lst[0]
coefs = pd.rolling_apply(my_ts, 21, pf_wrapper)
```

UPDATE:

Since `pd.rolling_apply()` is unable to return a non-scalar, my current solution is the following:

```
def get_beta(ts, deg):
    coefs = polyfit(range(len(ts)), ts, deg = 3)[::-1]
    return coefs[deg]

b0 = pd.rolling_apply(my_ts, 21, lambda x: get_beta(x, 0))
...
b3 = pd.rolling_apply(my_ts, 21, lambda x: get_beta(x, 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with `rolling_apply`.  The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.stats.moments.rolling_apply.html) says that the applied function "must produce a single value from an ndarray input".  What it seems to actually mean is "must produce a value *that is or can be converted into a single float*".  If you follow up on the full exception traceback it leads you to this code in `algos.pyx`:

```
output = np.empty(n, dtype=float)
counts = roll_sum(np.isfinite(input).astype(float), win, minp)

bufarr = np.empty(win, dtype=float)
oldbuf = <float64_t*> bufarr.data

n = len(input)
for i from 0 <= i < int_min(win, n):
    if counts[i] >= minp:
        output[i] = func(input[int_max(i - win + 1, 0) : i + 1], *args,
                         **kwargs)
    else:
        output[i] = NaN
```

The error is raised on the line with `output[i] = func(...)`.  You can see that the output array is hardcoded to have dtype float.  The error you receive is the same as what you get if you attempt to convert a numpy array (of length more than 1) to a float:

```
>>> float(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    float(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

So what is happening is that it tries to assign the output of `polyfit` to a single element of the float ndarray, and fails because the output of polyfit is an array that can't be converted to a float.

This could be "fixed" by making `output` have dtype object, but this would slow things way down.

I think you have to consider `rolling_apply` as usable only for functions that return a single float.  To support non-scalar outputs, you would have to roll (har har) your own version of `rolling_apply`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, you can just add [0] to the lambda function:

```
coefs = pd.rolling_apply(my_ts, 21, lambda x: np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 3)[0])
```

It now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since rolling_apply has been deprecated, Nissar's solution also works with pd.rolling.apply method:

```
coefs = my_ts.rolling(21).apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 3)[0])
```

Of particular significance here is Nissar's use of range(len(x)) to satisfy the time component, which avoids the inability to use rolling.apply with a lambda function of two columns or series (since some placeholder count for the x (time) component would typically be in another column of a dataframe or another series).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create an IIR filter kind of expansion of a time series.
Eg: [1,2,3,4,5] with window = 2 should give: [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5]]

Here's my solution based on some bad coding practices but gets the job done.
Return index to a global dict/array from the rolling_apply() and throw away the return values. Solution is ready in the dict when rolling_apply returns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataDict = dict()
INDEX = 0

def windowFunc(w):
  global INDEX
  global dataDict
  dataDict[INDEX] = np.copy(w)
  INDEX = INDEX + 1
  return INDEX

dd = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
dd2 = pd.rolling_apply(dd, window=2, func = windowFunc)
print(list(dataDict.values()))
```